# Python - how to produce time in format 08:09:00 instead of 1900-01-01 08:09:00

Tags: python, time

this adds 30 minutes to the time such as 07:39

```
HOUR_ON = datetime.time(int(array_on[0]), int(array_on[1]))
HOUR_ON = str(HOUR_ON)
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(HOUR_ON,'%H:%M:%S')
HOUR_ON = a + datetime.timedelta(0,1800) # 1800 (30 mins) open door 30 mins later
```

but gives me "1900-01-01 08:09:00". How do I get it to give "08:09:00"

The important thing for me is the format - the code works and adds 30 minutes (as has been pointed out) I want to remove "1900-01-01" from this and leave only 08:09:00. I can't get strptime to work to do this. HOUR_ON will print 07:39 before I use

```
HOUR_ON = str(HOUR_ON)
```

when I have finished though I want "08:09:00". thanks

Addition

if update the code to

```
HOUR_ON = datetime.time(int(array_on[0]), int(array_on[1]))
HOUR_ON = str(HOUR_ON)
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(HOUR_ON,'%H:%M:%S')
HOUR_ON = a + datetime.timedelta(0,1800) # 1800 (30 mins) open door 30 mins later
HOUR_ON.strftime('%H:%m:%S')
print HOUR_ON
```

I still get 1900-01-01 08:09:00

Comment: no I don't see a duplicate - my code adds 30mins or 1800, don't think that matters - perhaps my title is badly worded but I am not asking how to add 30 minutes

Comment: `HOUR_ON.strftime('%H:%m:%S')` formats your datetime object as the string that you seek. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime. Note that your question is using `strptime` not `strftime`.

Comment: @SethDifley, I have added as suggested and updated my question - it sounds like what I want but I still get the same result

Comment: @tamus the code in your question used, but did not define, `array_on`. Even if `array_on` had been defined, the definition of `HOUR_ON` results in a runtime error because `datetime.time` takes exactly one argument, not two. My answer below walks through how to use the datetime library to convert a time string into a time-shifted string. If my answer below is useful, please mark accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is tested on both python 2 and python 3:

```
import datetime

#define the input time string
input_time_string = '23:39:00'
time_format_string = '%H:%M:%S'
print('input time string = {time}'.format(time=input_time_string))

#define a magic number that will be used by timedelta
seconds_in_30_minutes = 1800

#create a datetime object initialized to the time provided by the input time
#string defined above
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_time_string, time_format_string)

#add 1800 seconds to the datetime object
datetime_obj_plus_30_minutes = datetime_obj + datetime.timedelta(0, seconds_in_30_minutes)

#format the datetime object as a string containing only the time
output_time_string = datetime_obj_plus_30_minutes.strftime(time_format_string)

#print the time string
print('output time string = {time}'.format(time=output_time_string))
```

The above code prints the following to standard output showing that it works even when the next day is fewer than 30 minutes after the input time:

```
input time string = 23:39:00
output time string = 00:09:00
```

Comment: thanks for your time on this and reading to see that I wasn't needing to add minutes  - sorry I can't give you more than tick as the minuses here have brought my rep down. Your code works and helped me to get the answer - I needed to add two more lines to get all working as shown below

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me. I do not see any issues with your code. May be re-check the HOUR_ON variable

```
>>> HOUR_ON = str("08:09:00")
>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime(HOUR_ON,'%H:%M:%S')
>>> HOUR_ON = a + datetime.timedelta(0,1800)
>>> print HOUR_ON
1900-01-01 08:39:00
```

Comment: thanks but my code works - I am trying to format the output or take away the date - yes I don't understand python datetime and time fully

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, after I included answer from Seth, I then split the time and joined it together again as an int to get my answer with 30 minutes added in the format I needed - thanks everybody (even the -'s)

```
# add 30 mins to opening time
HOUR_ON = datetime.time(int(array_on[0]), int(array_on[1]))
HOUR_ONstr = str(HOUR_ON)
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(HOUR_ONstr,'%H:%M:%S')
HOUR_ON30 = a + datetime.timedelta(0,1800) # 1800 (30 mins) open door 30 mins later
HOUR_ONHMS = HOUR_ON30.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
array_on = HOUR_ONHMS.split(":")

# open and close times are set here
HOUR_ON = datetime.time(int(array_on[0]), int(array_on[1]))
```